# pandas apply function to series that checks if the first n characters matches a predefined string value, if so, the existing value needs to be updated

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to a pandas series that checks the first 3 as well as the first 2 characters of the values in the series.

If they match either, the first 3 or 2 characters (depending on which matched) needs to be replaced with '0', the rest of the characters remain the same.

The original dtype was of type 'O', I have tried converting this to type 'string' but still can't get this to work.

Sample data looks like so:

```
012xxxxxxx
+27xxxxxxxx
011xxxxxxx
27xxxxxxxx
etc...
```

The condition I am evaluating is if the first 3 characters == ***'+27'*** replace ***'+27'*** with ***'0'*** or if the first 2 characters == ***'27'*** replace ***'27'*** with ***'0'***

I have the following ***apply method*** but the values aren't being updated.

```py
def normalize_number(num):
       
    if num[:3] == '+27':
        # num.str.replace(num[:3], '0') ## First Method
        return '0' + num[4:] ## Second Method
    else:
        return num
        
    if num[:2] == '27':
        # num.str.replace(num[:2], '0') 
        return '0' + num[3:] 
    else:
        return num

df['number'].apply(normalize_number)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use a regex here. The the string starts with `27` with an optional `+` in front, replace with `0`:

```py
df['number2'] = df['number'].str.replace('^\+?27', '0', regex=True)
```

output:

```
        number     number2
0   012xxxxxxx  012xxxxxxx
1  +27xxxxxxxx   0xxxxxxxx
2   011xxxxxxx  011xxxxxxx
3   27xxxxxxxx   0xxxxxxxx
```

###### why your approach failed

your approach failed because your returned too early with an `else` statement. You should have used:

```py
def normalize_number(num):
    if num[:3] == '+27':
        return '0' + num[4:] ## Second Method
    elif num[:2] == '27':
        return '0' + num[3:] 
    else:
        return num
```

*NB. Use the regex approach above, it will be much more efficient*

##### regex

```
^      # match start of string
\+     # match literal +
?      # make previous match (the "+") optional
27     # match literal 27
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPdoyM/1)

Comment: Absolutely agree with you there. Everyone keeps telling me the same thing.  I'll get at it.

Comment: I added some comments on the regex and a link to a demo

Comment: Awesome  Thanks for link, this will definitely help me along the way